# Oracle SQL - Average turnover for this week higher than average weekly turnover for last year

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, oracle-sqldeveloper

What I have: 
A table with daily turnover values for each product.

What I need:
To extract names and values of products that have an average daily turnover for current week larger than the average weekly turnover for the last year (52 weeks).

Unfortunately, oracle says that single-row subquery returns more than one row, and I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

```
SELECT NAME, AVG(TURNOVER)/52
FROM DAILY_STATS
WHERE TYPE=243 AND T_DATE >= SYSDATE - 365
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING AVG(TURNOVER)/52 > 0 
AND 
AVG(TURNOVER) > 
(SELECT AVG(TURNOVER)
FROM DAILY_STATS
WHERE TYPE=243 AND T_DATE >= TO_DATE(TRUNC(sysdate, 'DAY'),'DD/MM/YYYY')
GROUP BY NAME);
```

Comment: Please add some example data and expected output of your query - your requirements are not 100% clear (at least not to me).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(TURNOVER)
FROM DAILY_STATS
WHERE TYPE=243 AND T_DATE >= TO_DATE(TRUNC(sysdate, 'DAY'),'DD/MM/YYYY')
GROUP BY NAME
```

Your sub query is returning more than one value.

`AVG(TURNOVER) >` Here the `>` operator is scalar operator and can compare only one value.

Possible solutions are

```
AVG(TURNOVER) > all
(SELECT AVG(TURNOVER)
FROM DAILY_STATS
WHERE TYPE=243 AND T_DATE >= TO_DATE(TRUNC(sysdate, 'DAY'),'DD/MM/YYYY')
GROUP BY NAME);
```

OR

```
AVG(TURNOVER) > ANY
(SELECT AVG(TURNOVER)
FROM DAILY_STATS
WHERE TYPE=243 AND T_DATE >= TO_DATE(TRUNC(sysdate, 'DAY'),'DD/MM/YYYY')
GROUP BY NAME);
```

The operators `> ANY` and `> all` converts scalar operator to multi row operator.
Mind you this may or may not conform with your logic.

EDIT: Answered too early. Correcting now.

EDIT2:

Syntactically, the query fetches the result, however as Frank mentioned your logic seems to be a bit off

**Table Content**

```
+------+----------+------+-----------+
| NAME | TURNOVER | TYPE |  T_DATE   |
+------+----------+------+-----------+
| ABC  |      100 |    2 | 03-MAY-16 |
| ABD  |      200 |    2 | 02-MAY-16 |
| ABE  |      300 |    2 | 01-MAY-16 |
| ABF  |      400 |    2 | 30-APR-16 |
| ABF  |      500 |    2 | 29-APR-16 |
| ABG  |      600 |    2 | 28-APR-16 |
| ABH  |      700 |    3 | 27-APR-16 |
| ABH  |      800 |    2 | 28-APR-16 |
| ABH  |      900 |    2 | 28-APR-16 |
| ABH  |     1900 |    2 | 28-APR-16 |
| ABH  |     2900 |    2 | 28-APR-16 |
| ABH  |     3900 |    2 | 28-APR-16 |
| ABH  |   113900 |    2 | 28-APR-16 |
| ABH  |  1213900 |    2 | 28-APR-16 |
+------+----------+------+-----------+
```

**Query**

```
SELECT NAME, AVG(TURNOVER)/52
FROM DAILY_STATS
WHERE TYPE=2 AND T_DATE >= SYSDATE - 365
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING AVG(TURNOVER)/52 > 0 
AND 
AVG(TURNOVER) > any
(SELECT AVG(TURNOVER)
FROM DAILY_STATS
WHERE TYPE=2 AND T_DATE >= sysdate-7
GROUP BY NAME);
```

**RESULT**

```
+------+-------------------------------------------+
| NAME |             AVG(TURNOVER)/52              |
+------+-------------------------------------------+
| ABG  | 11.53846153846153846153846153846153846154 |
| ABD  | 3.84615384615384615384615384615384615385  |
| ABE  | 5.76923076923076923076923076923076923077  |
| ABF  | 8.65384615384615384615384615384615384615  |
| ABH  | 3676.373626373626373626373626373626373627 |
+------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, neither of these will return the correct rows - you're comparing apples with oranges (weekly AVG over the past year for one product with AVG of last week for all other products instead of the same product).

Comment: I need to compare the weekly turnover for the whole last 52 weeks to the average weekly turnover for the current week for the same products (compare the yearly one of product_one to weekly one of product_one, product_two to product_two etc.). I need a list of products that have a higher weekly turnover than the the average weekly turnover for last 52 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You're not filtering the input data for your scalar subquery correctly - since you want to compare averages for the same product, you need to filter by the name of the product:

```
with daily_stats(type, t_date, turnover, name) as (
  select 243, date '2016-01-01', 200, 'P' from dual union all
  select 243, date '2016-05-04', 300, 'P' from dual union all
  select 243, date '2016-01-01', 200, 'Q' from dual)   
SELECT NAME, AVG(TURNOVER)/52
  FROM DAILY_STATS ds1
 WHERE TYPE=243 AND T_DATE >= SYSDATE - 365
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING AVG(TURNOVER)/52 > 0 
AND 
AVG(ds1.TURNOVER) <
(SELECT AVG(ds2.TURNOVER)
 FROM DAILY_STATS ds2
 WHERE ds2.TYPE=243 AND ds2.T_DATE >= TO_DATE(TRUNC(sysdate, 'DAY'),'DD/MM/YYYY')
 and ds2.name = ds1.name);
```

This will resolve your "single-row subquery ..." error. However, I'm not 100% sure your logic is sound - do you really want to compare *daily* averages with *weekly (i.e. over 7 days)* ones ?